# How do we limit who can invoke a chaincode function in Hyperledger v1?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In Hyperledger v0.6, we are able to use ReadCertAttribute to get attributes like role and userid.

We use the attribute role to limit who can invoke a particular function.  And we use the attribute userid (which is equal to the enrollment ID), to tag the owner of a particular asset.

In Hyperledger v1, we discovered that ReadCertAttribute is not implemented.

Is there an alternative way to limit who can invoke a particular function given that we cannot retrieve the attribute role of the invoker?

Is there a way to tag an asset given that we cannot retrieve the attribute userid.  There was a suggestion to use GetCreator.  However, GetCreator returns a certificate rather than the enrollment ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetCreator` will return you an X.509 certificate which you can deseriallize to extract the id from it. Actually you once deseriallize you can get all attributes you used to have back in v0.6.